# how to add routing to knockout app

Tags: knockout.js, sammy.js, pager.js

today I have a problem with my app write in knockout js. I want to add deep routing to my app but I don't do this never before. I don't know how to start and how to modyfi or change my app. I saw an example in [this link](https://github.com/alexbihary/knockout-router) but I don't know how to use that in my app. I need a help from someone who have more experience in implement routing in knockout. My app is available in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g0xgLmm3/) code is below

HTML

```
<form action="#"> 
    <input placeholder="Search…" type="search" name="q" data-bind="value: query, valueUpdate: 'keyup'" autocomplete="off"> 
  </form>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        <ul class="name-list" data-bind="foreach: filteredPeople">
          <li data-bind="attr:{class: $index == 0 ? 'active' : ''}, click: toggleshowMoreInfo" role="button">
            <span class="full-name" data-bind="text: fullName"></span>
          </li>

          <div class="hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg" data-bind="slideVisible: showMoreInfo, fadeDuration:600,template: {name: 'person-template'}"></div>
        </ul>

      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-8 col-lg-8 hidden-xs" data-bind="foreach: filteredPeople">
        <div class="row" data-bind="slideVisible: showMoreInfo, fadeDuration:600,template: {name: 'person-template'}"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <!-- template for presonal information -->
  <script type="text/html" id="person-template">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
      <p><span data-bind="text: fullName"></span></p>
    </div>
  </script>
```

JS

```
var data = [
  {
    "index": 0,
    "name": [{
      "first": "Barlow",
      "last": "Moore"
    }]
  },
  {
    "index": 1,
    "name": [{
      "first": "Valeria",
      "last": "Meadows"
    }]
  },
  {
    "index": 2,
    "name": [{
      "first": "Constance",
      "last": "Singleton"
    }]
  },
  {
    "index": 3,
    "name": [{
      "first": "Wilder",
      "last": "Steele"
    }]
  }
];

  var stringStartsWith = function (startsWith, string) {          
    string = string || "";
    if (startsWith.length > string.length)
        return false;
    return string.substring(0, startsWith.length) === startsWith;
  };

  ko.bindingHandlers.slideVisible = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {
      var value = valueAccessor();
      var valueUnwrapped = ko.unwrap(value);
      var duration = allBindings.get('fadeDuration') || 400;
      if (valueUnwrapped == true)
        setTimeout(function(){ $(element).fadeIn(duration); }, duration);
      else
        $(element).fadeOut(duration);
    }
  };

  /* show all data from json */
  function PersonInfo(data) {
    this.firstName = ko.observable(data.name[0].first);
    this.lastName = ko.observable(data.name[0].last);
    this.fullName = ko.computed(function() {
      return this.firstName() + " " + this.lastName();
    }, this);

    this.showMoreInfo = ko.observable(false);
    this.toggleshowMoreInfo = function () {
      this.showMoreInfo(!this.showMoreInfo())
    }
  }

  function PersonInfoViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.query = ko.observable('');
    self.mappedPersonalData = $.map(data, function(item) {  
      return new PersonInfo(item) 
    });
    self.filteredPeople = ko.computed(function () {
        return self.mappedPersonalData.filter(function (value) {
            if(self.query() === '' || self.query() === null){
               return true; //no query
            }
            if (stringStartsWith(self.query().toLowerCase(), value.firstName().toLowerCase()) || stringStartsWith(self.query().toLowerCase(), value.lastName().toLowerCase())){
               return true;
            }
            return false;
        });
    }); 
  }

  var viewModel = new PersonInfoViewModel();

  $(document).ready(function() {
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
  });
```

Comment: You might want to take a look at Sammy.js:
http://sammyjs.org/intro and http://www.softfinity.com/blog/an-simple-introduction-to-url-routing/

Comment: I check softfinity, I see what he doing on example and how it work where you have different links like contact about etc. But I can't understand how I can apply this for my currert project. If I understand this correct I can use example full name to bing this as id attribute and show this in link?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

As previously commented by Rafael, use Sammy.js if you're creating a One Page JS app. I would not recommend having knockout do the routing, as it is not designed for that purpose.

Comment: I want to add routing to my app. what it mean? Example if I click to a list element I want to see on url somethin like this: localhost/app/first-person and home link look like localhost/app/. I see examples where you have typical nav like contact about us etc but I dont have it. I dont know maybe is a better way to use routing in my app. My problem is in how to use example Sammy.js to my example. If someone can show my working example I will be greatfull.